# VHDL MUX select with constant

Tags: vhdl, hdl, mux

I have a constant defined in my VHDL package.

```
constant USE_OSD : integer := 0;
```

And this is something that I change prior to synthesis in my package. I would like to use this constant as my MUX select line in my VHDL code. How can I do this?

for example, something like:

```
 s_out <=  path_a WHEN (USE_OSD = 0) else path_b;
```

Thanks,

--Rudy

Comment: That looks fine. What's the problem?

Comment: You have to add the package to the VHDL file you are working on, with `library work;  use work.my_package.all;`

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with a MUX select line.

Depending on the value of this constant, this is either elaborated as: `s_out <= path_a;` or as `s_out <= path_b;`. There will never be a mux.

As a way of learning, please consider running this through a synthesis tool and looking at the results.

Comment: The term "mux" may not be accurate, but if the intent is to use a constant to choose between two signal assignments, I don't see anything particularly wrong with this approach.

Comment: I agree that there is nothing wrong with the approach. I just wanted to point out that there is no mux inferred. This is in fact a good way to infer _less_ logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think u looking for an if generate. This is like a preprocessor Command in C.

Example:

```
path_a: if USE_OSD = 0 generate
   s_out <= path_a;
end generate path_a;
path_b: if USE_OSD /= 0 generate
   s_out <= path_b;
end generate path_b;
```

I think VHDL 2008 also allowse else generate.